# Alterar text do Preview (Xtrareport)

Tags: winforms, xtrareport

gostaria se tem como alterar o texto do `Preview` de um relatório `Xtrareport`.

Veja imagem abaixo :

[image: preview do xtrareport]

Comment: Está usando csharp? Poderia colocar algum código relevante na pergunta?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
XtraReport1 relatorio = new XtraReport1();
relatorio.CreateDocument();
PrintPreviewFormEx printPreviewFormEx = new PrintPreviewFormEx();
printPreviewFormEx.Text = "Título do Relatório";
printPreviewFormEx.PrintingSystem = relatorio.PrintingSystem;
printPreviewFormEx.Show();
```